# I am trying to run autoencoder_layers.py using keras on gpu but i get this error

Tags: python, neural-network, gpu, keras, autoencoder

autoencoder_layers.py [github code](https://github.com/nanopony/keras-convautoencoder/blob/master/autoencoder_layers.py)

```
import theano
from keras import backend as K
from keras.backend.theano_backend import _on_gpu
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Layer
from theano import tensor as T
from theano.sandbox.cuda import dnn
```

but I get this error:

```
 /home/hoda/anaconda2/bin/python /home/hoda/Downloads/keras-convautoencoder-master/autoencoder_layers.py
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 970M (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN not available)
Using Theano backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hoda/Downloads/keras-convautoencoder-master/autoencoder_layers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.backend.theano_backend import _on_gpu
ImportError: cannot import name _on_gpu
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment the line `from keras.backend.theano_backend import _on_gpu` and define `_on_gpu` as:

```
def _on_gpu():
    return theano.config.device[:3] == 'gpu'
```

It will fix your error.